# Messenger Button fixed to right bottom corner on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the "Message Us" button in the right bottom corner of the screen in mobile. I've managed to put it in desktop browsers, but I can't do it in mobile browsers. Any ideas out there?

Please check http://estudisimple.com/brain

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: That code is way over complex for such a simple button. There is inline css being added to the `fb-messengermessageus` element of `width:100%` which is what's causing the button to fall off the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for mobile:

```
.fb-messengermessageus{
  width: auto !important;
}
```